# How to show loading.gif on submit button and hide after load?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I'm wondering if anyone could help. I'm trying to add a loading.gif to a submit button then make it hide after the content is submitted. Here's the template for the page,

```
<div class="userpro userpro-users userpro-<?php echo $i; ?> userpro-<?php echo $layout; ?>" <?php userpro_args_to_data( $args ); ?>>

<div class="title"><?php

echo userpro_userwall_get_option( 'title' );

?>
</div>
</div>  
<div id="loading" style="display:none; text-align: center;"><img src="http://stolenmx.com/wp-    content/themes/load.gif" width="40px" height="40px" alt="Please Wait" /></div>
<div class="textarea"><textarea placeholder="<?php _e('Update Status...','userpro-userwall');?>"  id=userpost name="userpost"cols="50" rows="2" style="border: 1px solid #ccc;border-radius: 5px;width:  100%;"></textarea></div>
<div class="buttonpost"><button id="but1" type="submit"  name="Post_Now" value="Post Now" title="    <?php _e('Add to Wall','userpro-userwall'); ?>" onclick="user_post_data('userpost',<?php echo     get_current_user_id();?>); $('#loading').show();"><i class="fa fa-send fa-fw"></i><b><?php _e('Add to     Wall','userpro-userwall');?></b></button></div>

<div class="upload"><button id="but2" class=userwall_upload  data-filetype = 'photo'  type="submit"  name="upload_image" value="upload" data-allowed_extensions=jpg,png,jpeg,gif title="<?  php _e('Upload','userpro-userwall'); ?>"><i class="fa fa-image fa-fw"></i> <b><?php _e('Add  Photos','userpro-userwall');?></b></button></div>
<div id="userwalldata">
<?php
$args = array(
'posts_per_page'   => userpro_userwall_get_option( 'totalpost' ),
'order'            => 'DESC',
'include'          => '',
'exclude'          => '',
'meta_key'         => '',
'meta_value'       => '',
'post_type'        => 'userpro_userwall',
'post_mime_type'   => '',
'post_parent'      => '',
'post_status'      => 'publish',
'suppress_filters' => true ); 

$postslist = get_posts( $args );

foreach($postslist as $post)
{

global $userpro;
$user_id = get_post_meta( $post->ID,'user_id');

?>
<div class="userwall" id=<?php echo $post->ID?>>


<?php if($user_id[0]==get_current_user_id()) {?>
<div class="userwall_delete_post">
<button type="submit"  name="delete" value="delete" title="<?php _e('Delete','userpro-userwall');   ?>" onclick="userwall_delete_post(<?php echo $post->ID;?>);"><i class="fa fa-trash fa-fw"></i>     </button>
</div>
<?php }?>
<div class="userwall-post-content-img" data-key="profilepicture"><a  href="<?php echo $userpro-   >permalink($user_id[0]); ?>" title="<?php _e('View Profile','userpro'); ?>" ><?php echo get_avatar(   $user_id[0], "60" );  ?> </a></div> 

<div class="userwall-post-content">
            <div class="displayname"><a href="<?php echo $userpro->permalink($user_id[0]); ?>"><?  php echo userpro_profile_data('display_name', $user_id[0]); ?></a>
<?php $timestamp = strtotime($post->post_date); 
$new_date = date('d-M-Y h:i', $timestamp);?>
            <div class="post-date"><?php echo "Posted On ".$new_date;?></div>       </div>
<br>

<br>
<?php 

if($post->post_title=="imgpost")
echo '<img src="'.$post->post_content.'" width="auto" style="-moz-user-select: none;
border-radius: 10px;max-width:99%">';
else
{
echo $post->post_content;
}
?>
</div>
<div class="userwall-comment-data-<?php echo $post->ID;?>" id="userwall-comment" >
<?php 
$comments = get_post_meta($post->ID,'user_comment');

foreach($comments as $comment)
{

?>
<div class="userwall_comment_data" id="<?php echo $i ?>"><?php
if($comment['comment_userid']==get_current_user_id()) {
    ?><div class=userwall_delete_comment>
    <button type="submit"  name="delete" value="delete" title="<?php _e('Delete','userpro-  userwall'); ?>" onclick="userwall_delete_comment('<?php echo $post->ID;?>','<?php echo    $comment['comment_content'];?>',this);"><i class="fa fa-trash fa-fw-3"></i> </button></div>
<?php
}?><div class="userwall-comment-content-img" data-key="profilepicture"><a  href="<?php echo     $userpro->permalink($comment['comment_userid']); ?>" title="<?php _e('View Profile','userpro'); ?>" >  <?php echo get_avatar( $comment['comment_userid'], "40" );  ?> </a></div> 


<div class="userwall-post-content"><div class="displayname"><a href="<?php echo $userpro- >permalink($comment['comment_userid']); ?>"><?php echo userpro_profile_data('display_name',  $comment['comment_userid']); ?></a></div>

<?php 
$commenttimestamp = strtotime($comment['comment_date']);
$commenttime = date('d-M-Y', $commenttimestamp);?>
<div class="post-date"><?php echo "Commented On ".$commenttime;?></div><?php
echo "<br><p>".$comment['comment_content']."</p>";



echo "</div></div>";

}

?>
</div>
<div class="commenttext">
<a href="<?php echo $userpro->permalink(get_current_user_id()); ?>" title="<?php _e('View  Profile','userpro'); ?>"><?php echo get_avatar( get_current_user_id(), "40" );  ?></a>
<textarea id=userwall-comment-<?php echo $post->ID;?> placeholder="<?php _e('Write your reply and    hit enter...','userpro-userwall');?>"  onkeypress="user_post_comment('userwall-comment',<?php echo    get_current_user_id();?>,<?php  echo $post->ID;?>,event);" name="userwall-comment"cols="40" rows="1"   style="border: 1px solid #ccc;+border-radius: 6px;margin: 0px 0px 0px -5px;max- width:100%;width:445px;height:46px;margin-top: 6px;"></textarea>
</div>

</div>

<?php 


}

?>
</div>
<?php
global $wp_query,$wpdb;
$curauth = $wp_query->get_queried_object();
$post_count = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_type = 'userpro_userwall'     AND post_status = 'publish'");
if($post_count>=userpro_userwall_get_option( 'totalpost' ))
{
?>

<div class="socialwall-load-more" id="socialwall-load-more" data-max-pages="<?php  echo   userpro_userwall_get_option( 'totalpost' ) ?>"><span><?php _e('Load More','userpro-userwall')?>    </span></div>
<?php }?>
```

Here's what I have so far,

```
<div id="loading" style="display:none; text-align: center;"><img src="http://stolenmx.com/wp-    content/themes/load.gif" width="40px" height="40px" alt="Please Wait" /></div>

<div class="buttonpost"><button id="but1" type="submit"  name="Post_Now" value="Post Now" title="    <?php _e('Add to Wall','userpro-userwall'); ?>" onclick="user_post_data('userpost',<?php echo     get_current_user_id();?>); $('#loading').show();">
```

The loading.gif loads after entering content and pressing the button but it never hides after the content loads. Could anyone help out with a solution? Thanks

UPDATE:

Front end html,

```
<div class="post">


                                <h1 class="single dotted">Social Wall</h1>



                                <div class="userpro userpro-users userpro-607 userpro-float"     data-modal_profile_saved="Your profile has been saved!" data-template="socialwall" data- max_width="480px" data-uploads_dir="http://stolenmx.com/wp-content/uploads/userpro/" data- default_avatar_male="http://stolenmx.com/wp-content/plugins/userpro/img/default_avatar_male.jpg"  data-default_avatar_female="http://stolenmx.com/wp- content/plugins/userpro/img/default_avatar_female.jpg" data-layout="float" data-margin_top="0" data- margin_bottom="30px" data-align="center" data-skin="blue" data-required_text="This field is required"  data-password_too_short="Your password is too short" data-passwords_do_not_match="Passwords do not  match" data-password_not_strong="Password is not strong enough" data-keep_one_section_open="0" data- allow_sections="1" data-permalink="http://stolenmx.com/social-wall/" data-field_icons="1" data- profile_thumb_size="80" data-register_heading="Register an Account" data-register_side="Already a  member?" data-register_side_action="login" data-register_button_action="login" data- register_button_primary="Register" data-register_button_secondary="Login" data- register_group="default" data-register_redirect="0" data-type="0" data-login_heading="Login" data- login_side="Forgot your password?" data-login_side_action="reset" data-login_button_action="register"  data-login_button_primary="Login" data-login_button_secondary="Create an Account" data- login_group="default" data-login_redirect="0" data-rememberme="true" data-delete_heading="Delete  Profile" data-delete_side="Undo, back to profile" data-delete_side_action="view" data- delete_button_action="view" data-delete_button_primary="Confirm Deletion" data- delete_button_secondary="Back to Profile" data-delete_group="default" data-reset_heading="Reset  Password" data-reset_side="Back to Login" data-reset_side_action="login" data- reset_button_action="change" data-reset_button_primary="Request Secret Key" data- reset_button_secondary="Change your Password" data-reset_group="default" data-change_heading="Change  your Password" data-change_side="Request New Key" data-change_side_action="reset" data- change_button_action="reset" data-change_button_primary="Change my Password" data- change_button_secondary="Do not have a secret key?" data-change_group="default" data- list_heading="Latest Members" data-list_per_page="5" data-list_sortby="registered" data- list_order="desc" data-list_users="0" data-list_group="default" data-list_thumb="50" data- list_showthumb="1" data-list_showsocial="1" data-list_showbio="0" data-list_verified="0" data- list_relation="or" data-online_heading="Who is online now" data-online_thumb="30" data-online_showthumb="1" data-online_showsocial="0" data-online_showbio="0" data-online_mini="1" data- online_mode="vertical" data-edit_button_primary="Save Changes" data-edit_group="default" data-view_group="default" data-social_target="_blank" data-social_group="default" data-card_width="250px" data-card_img_width="250" data-card_showbio="1" data-card_showsocial="1" data-link_target="_blank" data-error_heading="An error has occured" data-memberlist_table="0" data-memberlist_table_columns="user_id,picture,name,country,gender,role,email_user,message_user" data-show_on_mobile="picture,name,country,email_user,message_user" data-memberlist_v2="1" data-memberlist_v2_pic_size="86" data-memberlist_v2_fields="age,gender,country" data-memberlist_v2_bio="1" data-memberlist_v2_showbadges="1" data-memberlist_v2_showname="1" data-memberlist_v2_showsocial="1" data-memberlist_pic_size="120" data-memberlist_pic_topspace="15" data-memberlist_pic_sidespace="30" data-memberlist_pic_rounded="1" data-memberlist_width="100%" data-memberlist_paginate="1" data-memberlist_paginate_top="1" data-memberlist_paginate_bottom="1" data-memberlist_show_name="1" data-memberlist_popup_view="0" data-memberlist_withavatar="0" data-memberlist_verified="0" data-memberlist_filters="0" data-memberlist_default_search="1" data-per_page="12" data-sortby="registered" data-order="desc" data-relation="and" data-search="1" data-exclude="0" data-show_social="1" data-registration_closed_side="Existing member? login" data-registration_closed_side_action="login" data-facebook_redirect="profile" data-logout_redirect="0" data-post_paginate="1" data-postsbyuser_num="12" data-postsbyuser_types="post" data-postsbyuser_mode="grid" data-postsbyuser_thumb="50" data-postsbyuser_showthumb="1" data-postsbyuser_taxonomy="category" data-postsbyuser_category="0" data-following_per_page="4" data-following_paginate="1" data-followers_per_page="4" data-followers_paginate="1" data-publish_heading="Add a New Post" data-publish_button_primary="Publish" data-history_public="0" data-history_title="Points History" data-history_type="mycred_default" data-history_number="10" data-badges_public="0" data-badges_title="Earned Badges" data-following_heading="Following" data-followers_heading="Followers" data-activity_heading="Recent Activity" data-activity_all="0" data-activity_per_page="10" data-activity_side="refresh" data-activity_user="0" data-emd_filters="1" data-emd_thumb="200" data-emd_social="1" data-emd_bio="1" data-emd_fields="first_name,last_name,gender,country" data-emd_layout="masonry" data-emd_per_page="20" data-emd_col_width="22%" data-emd_col_margin="2%" data-emd_accountstatus="Search by account status" data-emd_photopreference="Photo Preference" data-emd_country="Search by Country,dropdown" data-emd_gender="Gender,radio" data-emd_paginate="1" data-emd_paginate_top="1" data-i="607">

<div class="title">Social Wall </div>
</div>  
<div id="loading" style="text-align: center;"><img src="http://stolenmx.com/wp-  content/themes/load.gif" width="40px" height="40px" alt="Please Wait"></div>
<div class="textarea"><textarea placeholder="Update Status..." id="userpost" name="userpost"  cols="50" rows="2" style="border: 1px solid #ccc;border-radius: 5px;width: 100%;"></textarea></div>
<div class="buttonpost"><button id="but1" type="submit" name="Post_Now" value="Post Now"   title="Add to Wall" onclick="user_post_data('userpost',1); $('#loading').show();"><i class="fa fa-  send fa-fw"></i><b>Add to Wall</b></button></div>

<div class="upload"><button id="but2" class="userwall_upload ajax-file-upload" data-  filetype="photo" type="submit" name="upload_image" value="upload" data- allowed_extensions="jpg,png,jpeg,gif" title="Upload"><i class="fa fa-image fa-fw"></i> <b>Add  Photos</b></button></div>
<div id="userwalldata"><div class="userwall" id="291"><div class="userwall_delete_post">
<button type="submit" name="delete" value="delete" onclick="userwall_delete_post( 291);"><i  class="fa fa-trash fa-fw"></i> </button>
</div><div class="userwall-post-content-img" data-key="profilepicture"><a  href="http://stolenmx.com/profile/Admin/" title="_e('View Profile','userpro')"> <img  src="http://stolenmx.com/wp-content/uploads/bfi_thumb/5491a01f194c6- 1p9lseef4jgdq3ff9ccn4ooisj0hpjvp3pg9zukt8e6c.jpg" width="60" height="60" alt="" class="modified  avatar"></a> </div>
    <div class="userwall-post-content"><div class="displayname"><a  href="http://stolenmx.com/profile/Admin/"> Luke Day</a> <div class="post-date">Posted On 20-Dec-2014  10:14</div></div><br><br>test</div> <div class="userwall-comment-data-291" id="userwall-comment"> </div><div class="commenttext"> <a href="http://stolenmx.com/profile/Admin/" title="_e('View  Profile','userpro')"> <img src="http://stolenmx.com/wp-content/uploads/bfi_thumb/5491a01f194c6- 1p9lseef3v39xf7c2o2dtaexxa9pgyoktbse8fkrnxk4.jpg" width="40" height="40" alt="" class="modified  avatar"></a><a href="http://stolenmx.com/profile/Admin/"> Luke Day</a>
<textarea id="userwall-comment-291" onkeypress="user_post_comment('userwall- comment',1,291,event);" name="userwall-comment" cols="40" rows="1" style="border:solid 1px black;max- width: 100%;"></textarea></div></div>
</div>


<style type="text/css">

div.userpro-awsm-pic {
margin-left: -48px;
top: -48px;
}

div.userpro-awsm-pic img {
width: 86px;
height: 86px;
}

div.userpro,
div.emd-main,
div.emd-filters,
div.userpro-search-results,
div.userpro-label label,
div.userpro input,
div.userpro textarea,
div.userpro select,
div.userpro-field textarea.userpro_editor,
div.userpro-msg-overlay-content,
div.userpro-msg-overlay-content input,
div.userpro-msg-overlay-content textarea,
div.userpro-notifier
{
font-family: Roboto;
}


div.userpro-607 {
max-width: 480px;
            margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto;
            margin-bottom: 30px;
}



div.userpro-607.userpro-nostyle {
max-width: 250px;
}

div.userpro-607.userpro-users {
max-width: 100% !important;
}

div.userpro-607 div.userpro-user {
margin-top: 15px;
margin-left: 30px;
margin-right: 30px;
}

div.userpro-607 div.userpro-user a.userpro-user-img {
width: 120px;
height: 120px;
}
div.userpro-607 div.userpro-user a.userpro-user-img span {
top: -120px;
line-height: 120px;
}

div.userpro-607 div.userpro-user div.userpro-user-link {
width: 120px;
}

div.userpro-607 div.userpro-user a.userpro-user-img,
div.userpro-607 div.userpro-user a.userpro-user-img span {
border-radius: 999px !important;
}

div.userpro-607 div.userpro-list-item-i {
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
}


div.userpro-607 div.userpro-online-item-i {
width: 30px;
height: 30px;
}

div.userpro-607 div.userpro-online-item {
border-bottom: 0px !important;
padding: 10px 0 0 0;
}

div.userpro-607 div.userpro-online-item img.userpro-profile-badge,
div.userpro-607 div.userpro-online-item img.userpro-profile-badge-right {
max-width: 14px !important;
max-height: 14px !important;
}

div.userpro-607 div.userpro-profile-img {
width: 80px;
height: 80px;
}

div.emd-user {
width: 22%;
margin-left: 2% !important;
}




</style>


                                <div class="prdetails">
                                </p></div>

                            </div>
```

Comment: Are doing something with ajax on form submit? It would help if you could post the HTML generated by the PHP, as opposed to the PHP itself.

Comment: please only post relevant code. We shouldn't have to mentally parse your server code for a loading icon issue in client that has nothing to do with server code

Comment: Iv'e included the generated HTML and I believe it's just jquery, don't think ajax is used. 

And the only reason I pasted all the server code is because most of the time when I seek help I get asked for more code, more core to find the best solution. Thanks.

Comment: So you have a "Post now" button and when it's clicked, you call `user_post_data()` before showing the spinner. Presumably when `user_post_data()` has completed and inserted something into the page you want to hide the spinner. Did I get that correct? If so, could you post the contents of the `user_post_data()` function.

Comment: In which div you show the content after the button click? Is it this ...div class="userwall_comment_data"...? I am only asking because i think you can do this without ajax.

Comment: Yes, that's correct Jack, and the user_post_data() is generated depending on who writes what in the comments box.

Comment: Hi Peter, it's shown in, <div class="userwall-post-content"

Comment: We need a way of finding out when the function has returned. Can you post the contents of the `user_post_data()` function?

Comment: Hi Jack, could this be it? http://pastebin.com/Yy3nZ7Zm

Comment: Nope. That's PHP / HTML. We need the contents of the JavaScript function `user_post_data()`. Alternatively, could you post a link to your site?

Comment: My site is offline at the moment and only accessible over localhost. I'm using wordpress if that helps, I'm thinking it may be a default WP function for posts. What's the best way to find it?

Comment: Taking a slightly different tact, is there any other way of ascertaining that `user_post_data()` has completed? For example, is there a specific string that always gets inserted into a specific div? If so, what is the string and what is the div?

Comment: yes, it allways adds this line, <textarea id="userwall-comment-291" onkeypress="user_post_comment('userwall- comment',1,291,event);" name="userwall-comment" cols="40" rows="1" style="border:solid 1px black;max- width: 100%;"></textarea></div>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have one solution if your using ajax...

```
if you are doing something like calling ajax 
then right on button click  
this code
$('#loading').show(); or $('#loading').html('<img src="images/loading.gif">'); loading...');
```

and after competing process getting result from ajax hide that div

```
    $('#loading').hide(); or $('#loading').html();
or
```

if you are not using ajax then on your button click your calling user_post_data function that returning data so before this call

```
$('#loading').show();
```

and after getting data from function hide this div

Comment: Hi, I'm using jquery and I have this,
    
<div class="buttonpost"><button id="but1" type="submit"  name="Post_Now" value="Post Now" title="    <?php _e('Add to Wall','userpro-userwall'); ?>" onclick="user_post_data('userpost',<?php echo     get_current_user_id();?>); $('#loading').show();">

The code above is on the onclick= which shows the loader after clicking submit but it doesn't hide it?

Comment: so on click your calling this user_post_data function, so after completion function execution  $('#loading').hide(); this div but within that function scope

Comment: I think I understand, just need to find the user_post_data function.

Answer (score 0):

A check for the content length of that particular div could help you. But i don't know if it shows previous posts of the user. then you should compare old content length before the button click and the new one after the button click.

```
var content = $('.userwall-post-content').html();
var len1 = content.length;
$('#but1').on('touchstart click',function() {
$('#loading').show();
var len2 = content.length;
if (len2.length > len1.length) {
$('#loading').hide();
}
});
```

Comment: This will fail as you are checking the length of the div straight off the bat. You need to repeat the check for a sensible amount of time using `setInterval` which could theoretically work. However, it would be much cleaner to wait for the original function to return, then do whatever.

Comment: You are right @JackZelig this is a way and the use of setInterval is a must here, but as i remember userpro uses mostly ajax in almost everything in WP i think that there are code parts that are missing from this question.

Comment: There is code parts missing. I didn't want to post the whole lot so I just posted what I thought was relevant. I'm searching for the function now using notepad++ When I tried to use ajax methods I kept getting 'function undefined' errors.

Comment: I think that you could use the above example in your ajax response and check the length of that certain div before and after post. This you would have to do only if the user has previous posts showing in that div and i should not forget to mention that there is html code inside that div anyway so comparing to 0 it would not give the correct outcome. of course there could be an easier way if all code is available and there is a clearer view. Regarding function undefined i think i have seen that issue before in some work i was doing with userpro, but i don't remember the fix.

Answer (score 0):

When the user clicks the button, you could check for the presence the textarea inside of the div (which would indicate that the content has loaded). If it's not there, you could repeat that check every half a second, for a period of ten seconds (for example). As soon as the content shows up, you can hide your spinner. If it doesn't show up after that, then presumably something has gone wrong.

Something like:

```
var i;
function isPresent(){
  if($(selector).length){
    hideSpinner();
    clearInterval(i);
  }
}

function hideSpinner(){
  $(spinner).remove();
}

$("button").on("click", function(){
  this.disabled = true;

  if(isPresent()){
    hideSpinner();
  } else {
    i = setInterval(isPresent, 500);
    setTimeOut(function(){ clearInterval(i); }, 10000);
  }
});
```

Comment: Yeah, it's only meant to give you an idea of what to do. You'll have to adapt it a little to your markup.